# How to identify bad peers that are connected to my node

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers

How do I know if it's a bad peer?

I see a lot of connections, but does the software filter out bad peers?
Or is it up to me to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with “bad peers”?

Answer (score -2):

#### Protocol & data deserialization

When your software is connecting to a peer, you are both sending raw data that respects a specific structure. It is the Bitcoin P2P protocol. So if a peer is sending bad data that you can't deserialize or that do not follow protocol, it is a "bad" peer. That's the first way.

#### Data integrity

The second way is to know data integrity of what the peer is sending you. For instance, if you asked a block, the peer would have to answer you with this block. However, this block might be invalid, and if it is, this peer is a BAD one. Another example, a checksum with SHA256d is used in the header of requests in the P2P v1. If it is incorrect, your software will detect it.

#### Conclusion

Bitcoin core follows its own specific network protocol. A peer which doesn't respect it will be a "bad" peer. There are plenty of consensus network rules. I just illustrated main ones.